# Google Chrome DevTool CSS Editor - Change doesn't take effect

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I’m having problem with Google Chrome DevTools, I used to edit and write CSS from the editor panel under sources. Recently, the CSS editor doesn’t take effect anymore. I can’t figure out how to make it work. Does anyone have same issue? How can I solve it?

[image: Chrome-DevTool-CSS-Editor]

Comment: just checked now in my case, and it working, but in the past, I don't know why but wasn't working. maybe try updating the browser. (I tried on 3 lines css file, and also in bigger project like stackoverflow code itself and is working fine)

Comment: Also working for me on Chromium: 105.0.5195.102

Comment: Just updated the browser, but it is still not working.

Comment: For me it won't work in Shopify sites, but will work in all other sites.